# threejs water2 changing reflection state

Tags: three.js

there is a strange irregularity happening with my attempt of implementing the water2.js material onto a long surface that i can't explain.
When I start my app, the water is rendered correctly (see screenshot 1).

[->water showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjGVk.jpg)

The player moves forward quite a bit and suddenly the water turns into what you can see in screenshot 2.

[->water not showing correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkYFV.jpg)

I can't explain why or how it happens as it starts out exactly as I want it.
Anybody stumbled upon this before? How can I prevent it from turning into this solid mirror of my scene background?

DevBrowser: **Chrome65**
Threejs: **r91**

**Example code**

Using these three scripts from the three.js examples

```
<script src="js/objects/Reflector.js"></script>
<script src="js/objects/Refractor.js"></script>
<script src="js/objects/Water2.js"></script>
```

As seen here: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_water.html

```js
var splines = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( [
 new THREE.Vector3( -10, 0, 10 ),
 new THREE.Vector3( -5, 5, 5 ),
 new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 ),
 new THREE.Vector3( 5, -5, 5 ),
 new THREE.Vector3( 10, 0, 10 )
] );

//my curve is generated through waypoints so I inserted the standard curve as a stand in

    
var waterGeo = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(splines, 100, 4, 8, false);

var water = new THREE.Water( waterGeo, {
          color: 0xffffff,
          scale: 1,
          flowDirection: new THREE.Vector2( 1, 0 ),
          textureWidth: 1024,
          textureHeight: 1024
      } );

scene.add(water);
```

**Example2**
*I recreated a similar effect, where after one camera turn the water turns black and will not go reflective anymore*
**working example here:** http://staging.onewavestudios.com/waterexample/

```js
    //skybox
        var path = "assets/skybox/";
        var format = ".jpg";
        var skymaterials = [
        path + "ft" + format,
        path + "bk" + format,
        path + "up" + format,
        path + "dn" + format,
        path + "rt" + format,
        path + "lf" + format
        ];
        var skybox = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader().load(skymaterials);
        skybox.format = THREE.RGBFormat;

    //scene setup
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = skybox;
    
    //camera
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,0.1,1000);
        camera.position.set( 20, 0, 25 );
  camera.lookAt( scene.position );
        scene.add(camera);

    //lights
        var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xbbffff, 0.5 );
        scene.add(ambientLight);

    //objects
        //box1 - representation for the arms in my scene
        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 5, 5 );
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xbada55, envMap: skybox, reflectivity: 0.1 } );
        material.shadowSide = THREE.DoubleSide;
        material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
  var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        cube.position.y += 8;
        cube.position.z += 5;
  scene.add( cube );

        var splines = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
            new THREE.Vector3(-10, 0, 10),
            new THREE.Vector3(-5, 5, 5),
            new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
            new THREE.Vector3(5, -5, 5),
            new THREE.Vector3(10, 0, 10)
        ]);
        //my original curve is generated through waypoints so I inserted the standard curve as a stand in

        //waterbody
        var waterGeo = new THREE.TubeBufferGeometry(splines, 100, 4, 8, false);
        var water = new THREE.Water(waterGeo, {
            color: 0xffffff,
            scale: 1,
            flowDirection: new THREE.Vector2(1, 0),
            textureWidth: 1024,
            textureHeight: 1024
        });
        scene.add(water);

        //waterslide - representation
        var material2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: skybox, reflectivity: 0.8 } );
        material2.shadowSide = THREE.DoubleSide;
        material2.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        var container = new THREE.Mesh( waterGeo, material2 );
        container.position.y -= 5;
  scene.add( container );

    //renderer
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
  renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        animate();

    //render
        function animate() {
                camera.rotation.z += 0.005;
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
   }
   function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TubeWater Example</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/objects/Water2.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/objects/Reflector.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/objects/Refractor.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @werner, I will see how I can single it out

Comment: I added some explanatory code - hope that helps in understanding what I'm doing. The camera follows along the same curve.

Comment: Do you have a link to the three.js demo for the water that you are using?

Also, if you could post a working example of your code that would make it much easier to figure out.

Comment: @manthrax I can't see how I can import the external water2 scripts required to get a demo running. Updated my original post with the dependencies & demo link, hope that helps to get the point across somewhat?

Comment: I notice in the second shot, I can see the grid of the ground plane.. is the camera+player avatar moving below the ground plane? Can you maybe move the whole path up above the ground plane and see if that changes the behavior?

Comment: `THREE.Water` is intended to be used with flat geometries. Same for `THREE.Reflector` and `THREE.Refractor` which are internally used.

Comment: @manthrax good idea, but unfortunately same result.

Comment: @Mugen87 I read about it only being usable with planar geometries, but that does not explain why it does work fine for the first 120 units or so and then suddenly shifts once the camera reaches a certain point... This is also reproducable, on every reload it works fine, at some point I get a `[Violation] 'requestAnimationFrame' handler took 110ms` in the console and then it shifts into state2 until I reload the app

Comment: @Mugen87 I reread my comment and it could come over as criticism, which it is certainly not. I admire your work on this script, just want to understand why this happens, if it is fixable or if I have to think of a completely different approach to make that water run down the slide

Comment: @werner I added an example which shows a similar effect happening, so I assume this has to do with camera angle and form of the water object. What I do not get is why it snaps into state2 and will not go back into the correct state1 ever again...

Comment: Sry, I don't know the exact reason for this visual result. The only thing I can say is that your approach is definitely invalid since `THREE.Reflector` assumes a flat reflection plane. Thus, the calculated reflections for the tube geometry are wrong. Same for the refractive part.

Comment: @Mugen87alright, so I guess it would also be incorrect if I lower the `radial segments` down to 2, or is that processed as a planar surface then? Because I can't think of a better way to implement a planar surface following along a curved path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gotta validate what @Mugen87 is saying

> THREE.Water is intended to be used with flat geometries. Same for THREE.Reflector and THREE.Refractor which are internally used

I'm getting the same/similar artifacts on a spherical object when applying the [Refractor](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_refraction) onto it. In my case (possibly yours as well) when the scene initiates and the camera's point of view doesn't have to calculate any objects behind the refracted geometry the shader looks fine, as soon as I move the camera while it has other geometry behind it, it repeats a black silhouette of the geometry and remains in that line of sight for the remainder of the scene. So what I'm thinking is the cause is when the rays that are calculating the refractions, if the ray hits the backface of the geometry from line of sight, then this artifact occurs. I'd like to point out I'm no expert and learning threejs myself so due to the likely chance that I haven't conveyed my input ideally I've created an illustration using your scenario.

***Cause:***
[Possible cause of artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DQni.jpg)

So a possible solution for your situation might be as follows:

***Possible Solution:***
[Possible solution illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgvSN.jpg)

So by essentially creating a "semi" flat face for the shader to only have to calculate 1 side you might be able to achieve your desired effect, however be careful as to how much of a curve you place on the geometry carrying your "water" to avoid those backfaces being visible.

Also keep in mind that technically you aren't creating dynamic simulations here, so the geometry doesn't have to be fundamentally "correct". So By doing something like the following you're reducing the renderer's need to calculate something thats not really necessary. So you can just have your water geometry protruding the walls of your slide like so: (wasn't sure what the purple geometry is meant to be but looks like a slide to me lol)

[Possible Geometry Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d6yp.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the food for though @zSavic, I will make an attempt with this one. I sounds good to me logic wise. Out of curiosity, how did you fix your sphere problem?

Comment: My scenario there isn't really a fix other then using a custom shader which calculates the ray casts differently. This is only because the sphere is actually a light bulb shape part of my logo I'm trying to make transparent while refracting the inner filament of the lightbulb so my scenario is a whole lot more complex, been struggling for a few weeks now trying to achieve this effect with little success, however have learned alot in the process lol. Anyway I'd love to know if you manage to rectify your artifacts by removing that bottom side of the geometry. Hopefully I've helped in some way.

Comment: Well so I tried to implement a flat shape extruded geometry, as well as reduce the TubeGeometry Segments down to 2, to make it flat, thus have no backside that could trace back reflection/refraction information. Same thing happened though, as soon as the camera angle changed (the slide going downwards) it would do the very same thing. So I assume it has its root cause somewhere else. I singled out the use of reflection and refraction and it turns out ones refraction is removed at least the transparency works. So the cause must be the refraction component in combination with camera angle...

Comment: would you be willing to share your code across a github repo so that I can go through it and have a look myself?

Comment: in general yes and thanks for the offer - but it's a closed source project, so I unfortunately may not share it at this point